CPU Supports msse4_2, but Cannot Compile Emscripten Project With msse4_2 Flag
$ grep -q sse4_2 /proc/cpuinfo && echo "SSE 4.2 suported"|| echo "SSE 4.2 not supported"
"SSE 4.2 suported"

But if I add flag -msse4.2 I get the following error:
C:\Users\user\Documents\habr\emsdk-main\upstream\lib\clang\19\include\mmintrin.h:14:2: error: "This header is only meant
      to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"
   14 | #error "This header is only meant to be used on x86 and x64 architecture"

I can compile my project only with -msse flag. How to compile it with -msse4.2?

What processor do you have?

Tell us the version of clang you are using and how you installed it, the exact contents of a minimal source file that causes the error, and the exact command line you used to compile.

Note this probably doesn't have anything to do with the processor you actually have.  Even if your CPU didn't support SSE4.2, in general it should work to compile code for a different set of processor features than the build machine has.  You wouldn't be able to run the program on that computer, but you can still compile it.  You'd be able to run the resulting executable if you copied it to another computer that did have the necessary features.
